# How to group by a list of objects and declare this list as an attribute of a viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Basically I have this class

```
public class Gasto
{
    public int IdTienda { get; set; }
    public int IdGasto { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string ConceptoDeGasto { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
    public string TipoDeGasto { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdVenta { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaVenta { get; set; }

    public virtual Tienda Tienda { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to build a ViewModelClass like this

```
public class CorteConVentas
{
    // STILL NO ATRIBUTE -- THIS IS THE QUESTION
}
```

Here is the code for the controller where I will build a List of Gasto grouped by TipoDeGasto

```
var gastos = db.Gastos.Where(g => g.IdGasto >= corte.DesdeIdGasto && g.IdGasto <= corte.HastaIdGasto).ToList();

var GD     = gastos.GroupBy(u => u.TipoDeGasto).Select(grp => new { TipoGasto = grp.Key, gastos = grp.ToList() } ).ToList();
```

As you can see the variable "GD" is a List of Strings (TipoGasto) with List of Gasto.

**¿The issue (question) is this GD how can I declare it as an attribute of my viewModelClass?**

I tried something like this for the ViewModel

```
public class CorteConVentas
{
    public List<string, List<Gasto>> listaGastosAgrupada { get; set; }
}
```

But there is something wrong. The output of the error says:

> Using the generic type List requires 1 type arguments

Here is the output after grouping by
[image]

**Finally the solution as @Ziv Weissman said was not to use an anonymous type**

So I created a class like this

```
public class CorteConVentas
{
    public List<GastosAgrupados> listaGastosAgrupada { get; set; }
}

public class GastosAgrupados
{
    public string TipoGasto { get; set; }
    public List<Gasto> gastos { get; set;}
}
```

And then in the controller when creating the grouped list I did this

```
var gastos = db.Gastos.Where(g => g.IdGasto >= corte.DesdeIdGasto && g.IdGasto <= corte.HastaIdGasto).ToList();

var gd     = gastos.GroupBy(u => u.TipoDeGasto).Select(grp => new GastosAgrupados { TipoGasto = grp.Key, gastos = grp.ToList()) } ).ToList();
```

Thanks to all for helping me.

Comment: You cannot use 2 arguments in generic list, only one (List<string>). You can use Dictionary or KeyValuePair instead, see my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare a variable of anonymous type:

```
.Select(grp => new { TipoGasto = grp.Key, gastos = grp.ToList() } )
```

You must create another class which has these two props.
(or use a KeyValuePair)

Something like -

```
.Select(grp => new KeyValuePair<string,List<Gasto>> { Key = grp.Key, Value = grp.ToList() } )
```

Then you can create a strong typed prop.

```
public class CorteConVentas
{
  List<KeyValuePair<string,List<Gasto>>> PropName {get; set;}

}
```

Comment: It would need to be `List<object>` in order to support an anonymous type. However, that has the downside of not being very accessible later on. I think using a keyvaluepair as suggested here is a good solution,

Comment: You got it. I created a class instead of using an anonymous object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the solution

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, just look up `GroupBy()` in the docs, and see what it returns:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>
```

which is your case would be:

```
 public class CorteConVentas
 {
    public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Gasto>> listaGastosAgrupada { get; set; }
 }
```

Update:
Didn't notice the select after the GroupBy().  Try this:

```
public class GrupoGastos   // forgive my attempts at Spanish via Google Translate
{
     public string TipoGasto {get; set;}
     public List<Gasto> Gastos {get; set;}
}
```

then

```
var GD     = gastos.GroupBy(u => u.TipoDeGasto)
             .Select(grp => new GrupoGastos  
                  { TipoGasto = grp.Key, Gastos = grp.ToList() } )
             .ToList();
```

and finally:

```
public class CorteConVentas
{
    public List<GrupoGastos> listaGastosAgrupada { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't work. The linq query returns a List of anonymous type: string, List<Gasto>

Answer (score 1):

First, looks like you want a dictionary, not a list:

```
public class CorteConVentas
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<Gasto>> dictaGastosAgrupada { get; set; }
}
```

Second, that select list with two columns is going to give you trouble because it comes out as an anonymous type, and you have no way to declare a dictionary that will contain it.  Instead, just return the object:

```
var GD = gastos.GroupBy(u => u.TipoDeGasto).Select(grp);
```

So now you have `GD` which will let you enumerate over a list of `grp` objects.  You can add them to your dictionary like this:

```
foreach (var grp in GD) dictaGastosAgrupada.Add(grp.Key, grp.ToList());
```